# Get values from hidden <input> and use in jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm using gmaps.js as an interactive map on my site. The library allows you to add new map markers using long/lat co-ordinates. These are stored in my database, which I retrieve (along with other data) and echo this data like so:

```
<input id="lat" type="hidden" value="'.$lat.'"/>
<input id="long" type="hidden" value="'.$long.'"/>
```

There is other data being echoed, which is why you cannot see any `<?php ?>` tags - this is not a syntax mistake!

When I inspect element on the front end of my site, I can see the corresponding values have echoed successfully.

The issue I'm having is getting the values stored in the `<input>` tags into my jQuery function.

I want to get each of the long and lat values into here:

```
map.addMarker({
  lat: $lat,
  lng: $long,
  title: 'Lima',
  }
});
```

However as I understand, it's bad practice to echo PHP straight into a jQuery function.

Therefore, I have tried to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("lat").val();
 $("long").val();

 $.each( markers, function( index, value ) {

     var markers = {
            lat: value.lat,
            lng: value.long,
        }

 });

});
```

What do you suggest?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Use these $("#lat").val();
 $("#long").val();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the most advanced programmer, but I know a cleaner solution for your problem.

**JSON**
I understand you use PHP to retrieve your coordination, and you want your results displayed in a manner that Javascript can understand. Well, there's a better way for communicating between languages, it's called JSON. You can use it in PHP like this:

```
echo json_encode(["lat"=>$lat,"long"=>$long]);
```

Then you can retrieve it in Javascript like this:

```
var LatLong = JSON.parse('{"lat":"lat","lon":"long"}');
```

You can then use normal Javascript to retrieve both the Lat and the Long. Simply by doing LatLong.lat or something alike.

**AJAX**
Normally I would use AJAX for such things, but I suppose you don't have to.

**Finally, code**

Here's an example of how I would do it without AJAX

```
var parseString = '{"lat":"lat","long":"long"}'; // <-- Your PHP echo
var LatLong = JSON.parse(parseString);

    map.addMarker({
      lat: LatLong.lat,
      lng: LatLong.long,
      title: 'Lima',
      }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, I've tried what you've said however nothing seems to happen. I can get the json_encode to echo onto my page however nothing in the jQuery (and no errors either). Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oepwur1r/) which is exactly what's on my page. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well first of, your fiddle had errors, and you can't use jQuery without importing it. But you're on the right tracks. Here's a fiddle that confirms that js part works: https://jsfiddle.net/cer4dg7s/2/

Comment: I think that the `$(document).ready(function() {` made the script not run

Comment: Even when I use your example in the fiddle, nothing happens on my site at all, it all works up until I encode the data from php to jQuery, it appears nothing happens with said data. I have imported the relevant scripts needed, can confirm this as I can manually add a marker using [this](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/markers.html)

Comment: Can you perhaps give me the full php script? Obviously without GMaps key. There must be some information I'm missing, since I got it to work with your gmaps.js lib

Comment: I can provide my php script if needed, I have come across this error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id. Code: "var parseString = '{"lat":"51.585690","lon":"-0.311193"}'; // <-- Your PHP echo"

Comment: Just so we're clear. You are not putting the Javascript inside PHP are you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103638/discussion-between-napoleon-and-publicdisplayname).

Answer (score 2):

In first, in JQuery to select an element by Id you need to insert # before html id

```
 $("#lat").val();
 $("#long").val();
```

Then, I don't understand your code, but as I can see the two lines above don't make anything, get value from input element but don't save them to any variable.

Comment: Yes If target is only getting the values from input field than its fine. Anyway its jQuery not JQuery :p

Comment: ops, sorry. I was pretty sleepy last night.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the lng/lat data in a Database accessible by PHP. So, then you can just pass it to your client side javascript via json_encode(). The code below assumes you have a array of row objects from your database.

```
   <script>
   // Created data from PHP
   var mapData = <?php echo (!empty($data)) ? @json_encode($data) : '[]'; ?>;
   </script>
```

Then just continue as you were, using $.each(), etc.